# Flip card layout with multiple lines

Tags: css

I have try several card layouts I find from codepen, when the card contain several lines of content, they show up side by side not line by line.

How can I make a card layout that can have normal lines? I need to have a card front showing

```
Heading

altName1
altName2
Notes
CiteSource
```

and the photo in back.

Now the front of the card show like

```
 Hea alt alt Not Cit
 din Nam Nam es  eSo
 g   e1  e2      urce
```

Is it the style that create the card format affect the content of the card? How do I prevent that happen?

For example:

```
<div class="cards">
  <a class="card" href="#">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-front">
        <h2>Card With Safe Content</h2>
        <p>Second line</p>
        <p>Third line</p>
      </div>

      <p class="card-back">
        Nice short content.
      </p>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="card" href="#">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2 class="card-front">
        Card With Longer Content
      </h2>

      <p class="card-back">
        Longer but fully supported content. This card is now sized vertically by both its front and back faces — whichever happens to be the taller. We now have both front and back face in flow, and we don’t have any of the layout issues present when using absolute positioning. <br>Some light flex positioning allows cards with shorter content to be aligned as desired.
      </p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
:root { --time: 0.707s; }

.cards {
  display: grid;
}

.card {
  perspective: 40rem;
}

.card-body {
  display: flex;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: var(--time) transform;

  .card:hover &, .card:focus & {
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  }
}

.card-front, .card-back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.card-back {
  transform: rotateX(-180deg) translate(-100%, 0);
}

/* Make it Pretty */

body {
  line-height: 1.3;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.cards {
  grid-gap: 1.5rem;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  padding: 3rem;
  background: whitesmoke;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20rem, 1fr));
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  transition: z-index, transform calc(var(--time) / 4);
  transition-delay: var(--time), 0s;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  z-index: 0;
  
  &:hover {
    transition-delay: 0s;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  &:active {
    transform: scale(0.975);
  }
}

.card-body {
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  flex: 1;
}

.card-front, .card-back {
  @extend .shadow;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.card-front {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.04), 
              0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.04), 
              0 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.04), 
              0 8px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.04),
              0 16px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.04); 
}
```

Comment: Could you please show your css, so we can reproduce it?

Comment: the css is into the post, after the html